# Постройка правильного SQL-запроса в python3

Tags: python, mysql, sql

я только начал изучать SQL и практически ничего не знаю.

Суть запроса такая:
Ко мне приходят данные, которые я сохраняю в БД и на основе которых я заполняю остальные ячейки из других таблиц.

Пример:
Мне пришли такие данные:

30.06.2021, name_apps, name_club, FEE, 23423, 0

Они сохраняются в первые 6 ячеек(скрин ниже)
след ячейку он берет из другой таблицы, где есть строка с name_apps
след ячейку он берет из другой таблицы, где есть строка с name_club
след ячейку он берет из другой таблицы, если FEE то 0 * 10 * 50%(10 и 50% из другой таблицы), Если WIN то 0 * 10, Если HAG то 10

Вот что я уже сделал, возможно так будет понятней:

```
cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO requst_result (data, apps, club, result, id, value, token_course, rakeback, value_usd) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, "
            f"(SELECT storage_backing.token_course FROM storage_backing WHERE storage_backing.club_name = '{club}'),"
            f"(SELECT storage_backing.rb FROM storage_backing WHERE storage_backing.club_name = '{club}'),"
            f"(SELECT CASE WHEN '{fee}' = 'FEE' THEN ({value} * (SELECT storage_backing.token_course FROM storage_backing WHERE storage_backing.club_name = '{club}') * (SELECT storage_backing.rb FROM storage_backing WHERE storage_backing.club_name = '{club}')) "
                f"ELSE '3' END))",
            (date, app, club, fee, ids, value))
db.commit()
```

Умножение на (SELECT storage_backing.rb FROM storage_backing WHERE storage_backing.club_name = '{club}'), там хранится 50%, а мне нужно изменить на 0.5, так как он умножает просто на 50, а не на проценты

Comment: Вы сперва решите задачу на чистом SQL, а потом уже загоняйте запрос в питоновский код.

Comment: Тогда подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне на чистом SQL заменить данное значение {club} ?

Comment: А для этого недостаточно того, что написано в вопросе. Его вообще надо переписать с нуля. Выложить CREATE TABLE всех таблиц, INSERT INTO с примером данных (3-5 записей), данные для вставки (2-3 значения) и финальное состояние данных в таблицах, с подробным пояснением по каждому изменению.